# How to get instance of constant service in Angular

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs

I have the following in an ASP.NET MVC view:

```
<script>
    angular.module('DiagsDashboard.services').constant('settings', @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)));
</script>
```

Then later I want to get the value from the service like so:

```
 var $injector = angular.injector();
 var configSettings = $injector.get('settings');
```

However, I'm getting the error:
Unknown provider: settingsProvider

How can I get at those settings without using a controller?
I want to be able to test on the console too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not instantiting the injector correctly.
According to **[the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.injector)**, `$injector()` should be passed:

> A list of module functions or their aliases. [...] The ng module must be explicitly added.

So, in order for your instantiated injector to be "aware" of your app's artifacts, you need to instantiate it like this:

```
var $injector = angular.injector(['ng', 'yourApp']);
var configSettings = $injector.get('settings');
```

Comment: Excellent. I could always have created a controller but it simply pulls some settings from the server and uses it in some javascript.

Answer (score -1):

If you're looking to test the constant within a unit test, you can do something similar to:

```
// .. test setup ..
module('DiagsDashboard.services');
var configSettings;
inject(function(settings) {
    configSettings = settings;
});
// .. whatever you want to test now ..
```

Comment: Who says you can't get a constant/value from `$injector` ?